# Query running slow after adding criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

With much help from others I have this sql statement that calculates the difference in mileage (+ or -) between records in my table. Problem is that when I add a criteria (>0) to the the calculated value it dramatically slows my query. If I add a criteria to any other field then things run as expected (no long delay).

```
SELECT T1.Date, 
       T1.Route, 
       T1.BookingID, 
       T1.StreetNumber, 
       T1.Street, 
       T1.Arrive, 
       T1.Perform, 
       T1.Miles, 
       T1.Miles - (SELECT Miles 
                   FROM   Test1 AS T2 
                   WHERE  T2.Route = T1.Route 
                          AND T2.IDNumber = (SELECT Min(IDNumber) 
                                             FROM   Test1 AS T3 
                                             WHERE  T3.Route = T1.Route 
                                                    AND T3.IDNumber > 
                                                        T1.IDNumber)) AS 
       Difference 
FROM   Test1 AS T1 
GROUP  BY T1.Date, 
          T1.Route, 
          T1.BookingID, 
          T1.StreetNumber, 
          T1.Street, 
          T1.Arrive, 
          T1.Perform, 
          T1.Miles, 
          T1.IdNumber, 
          T1.Status, 
          T1.Activityy 
HAVING (( ( [T1].[Miles] - (SELECT Miles 
                            FROM   Test1 AS T2 
                            WHERE  T2.Route = T1.Route 
                                   AND T2.IDNumber = (SELECT Min(IDNumber) 
                                                      FROM   Test1 AS T3 
                                                      WHERE  T3.Route = T1.Route 
                                                             AND T3.IDNumber > 
                                                     T1.IDNumber)) ) > 0 )) 
ORDER  BY T1.IdNumber;
```

Comment: what DB are you using? Lead and Lag solutions can be DB specific

Comment: Egad that's an ugly query! +1 @ConradFrix

Comment: Your query is doomed to poor performance due to the double-nested corelated subquery. There is a better way to do this (but I can't the bothered working it out, sorry)

Comment: The `> 0` seems to belong to the `HAVING` clause. Are you saying it's fine before the `HAVING` clause? Since HAVING is executed nearly last, you should be able to do `HAVING Difference > 0`.

Comment: Yes if I remove the >0 the query runs fine. But I need the >0 so the only Differences with positive numbers are displayed

Answer (score 0):

Your difference is just finding the next record with miles.

If you database supports row_number() or lag(), then you can rewrite this query using windows functions rather than multiple self-joins.  That should fix the performance problem.

Otherwise, rewrite the query so the joins are in the "from" clause.  That should also fix the problem.

Finally, if you want to use a temporary table, put all the results in a temporary table and do the selection afterwards.  (This is not my preferred approach, but for a one-time query it might be the fastest solution.)

Comment: I am using Access 2010 and each row has a unique and sequential number (IDNumber). The query compares the mileage in the record above and returns the difference as either positive or negative number. I then use the >0 to filter out all records with a negative number so that my continuous form will show only those records with a positive number.